# I have an array stored in DataViewController and i want to to access the data of this array in another ViewController

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I know using custom `delegate` is an option for data traveling, but I want to know what's the best practice, also I have tried many other methods but the array in `Destination ViewController` always shows `nil`

Comment: send the data via segue

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to **bind** the data with the **destination** **viewcontroller**.

You have to pass **data** like this:-

```
let otherUserInstance = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("OtherUserProfileVC") as! OtherUserProfileVC
otherUserInstance.userID = self.data["UserId"]as! String //You can use array or dictionay instead of string
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(otherUserInstance, animated: true)



class OtherUserProfileVC: UIViewController {
    var userID = "" //declare as property of class
}
```

Comment: actually, I am not performing any navigation, I have 2 view controllers appearing in the same view...

Comment: Here we are giving solution on the basis of normal scenario if you are not cleared your question.
So basically this answer only tells us that we need to `bind up` the data with the view controller instance.

Comment: @cs832 are you getting my point?

Answer (score -1):

You may pass data by define array public like this way

```
var array: NSMutableArray!

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

 }
```

and then access it in other class like this way

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController 
{        
  override func viewDidLoad()
  {
     super.viewDidLoad()

    array = [1, 2, 3]
  }
}
```

Comment: why down vote? Give reason.

Comment: Using NSMutableArray instead of a Swift array is bad practice. Using it as implicitly unwrapped optional is even worse. And using a global variable like this is also very, very bad practice. So... three errors in six lines. The downvote is not really surprising, in this case, I guess. ;)

Comment: yeah using global variables is a very very bad practice.... but thnx for your response